# javascript prevent from submit

Tags: javascript, asp.net, submit

I have a textbox and a button. I just want to check textbox's value with javascript and prevent from submit, if it's null.

Here is .aspx:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button CssClass="addButtonBlack" ID="ButtonAddDriver" OnClientClick="return IsNull();" OnClick="ButtonAddDriver_Click" runat="server" Text="Ekle" />
```

And my javascript code:

```
function IsNull() {
        var success = true;

        var name = document.getElementById('TextBoxName');
        if (name.value == "") {
            name.style.borderColor = '#e52213';
            name.style.border = 'solid';
            success = false;
        }
        if (success)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
        }
```

It submits even textbox is null. How can I prevent it ?

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't you have something like: `OnClientClick="IsNull"`

```
function isNull(e) {
  if (it is null) e.preventDefault();
  else ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the JS function in the form's `onsubmit` attribute. For example,

```
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); IsNull();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery form event:

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```